# PHP script throwing syntax error after server move

Tags: linux, php, centos

I have just finished moving a WordPress site to a new server. Absolutely no changes have been made to the code, but when I try to view the site

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/crandall/www/website.com/wp-content/plugins/auto-featured-image/auto-featured-image.php on line 353
```

I don't see any such issue in the code, which I've pastebin'd below for reference; I haven't been able to find any occurrence of this issue in Google. The only thing I can think of is some *extremely* esoteric issue relating to PHP versions, as the original server was running PHP 5.2 and the new one is running 5.3.

http://pastebin.com/fLuFVEtB

Comment: What happens if you execute the code on your workstation? Can you replicate it? If so, it's a code issue. If not, it's more likely a server/configuration issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is short tags turned off on the new server?

There's an `<? endif; ?>` block just above the error that will be getting missed by PHP if short tags is off.

Comment: This is exactly it. D'oh. Very well answered, sir.